# Highcharts dynamic property updates when zooming

Tags: dynamic, zooming, highcharts

Is there anyway to change the Axis label sizes (fonts or sizes) when the chart is zoomed to some level? obviously there are some situations where you cannot put *font 24* when you see the whole diagram, but rather you want to make the fonts bigger when zoomed.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like the following code:

```
chart : {
    renderTo : 'container',
    zoomType: 'x',
    events: {
        selection: function() {
            this.yAxis[0].options.labels.style.fontSize = "20px";
        }
    }
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/qpEQZ/)

If you look the [**reference**](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.labels.style) you'll see that you can change other properties.